# javascript regular expression to recognize all special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regular expression for a stronger password which needs atleast one small case letter, upper case letter, one number, one special character  and has length=8 or above.

I have the below one regular expression.

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,}/
```

The problem with this one is it is not considering underscore('_') character as a special character.
How can I include this in the list of special characters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a *word-character* and thus not included in the `\W` (**not** word) class. Put the `\W` inside `[]` and add the `_` like

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{8,}/
```

That should do it

Regards

Comment: Thought it could by simplified to `/(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d\W_]).{8,}/`,  but that made me think - having `\d`, `a-z`, `A-Z` and `\W`+`_` matches everything. You' re basically just testing for a minimum length...